# TextView.setText not working due to threading?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-broadcast

I am running a thread that is receiving a string of data from a deice several times a second. I am trying to update a TextView to display that data, however once I start the thread in `connector.run()` I cant set the text of the TextView. Even when I run the `setText()` above the run method it did not work unless I commented out the run method call.

Here is where I am calling the run method.

```
readWeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //inputWindow.setText("helloooooooo worldddddd");
                    connector.run();
                    setInputWindow();
                   //readWeight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Here is my run method in another class.

```
public void run() {
            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {

                try {
                    output = "";
                    //read the data from socket stream
                    if(mmInStream != null) {
                        mmInStream.read(buffer);
                      for(byte b : buffer)
                      {
                          char c = (char) b;
                          if(c >=' ' && c <'z') {
                           // System.out.print(c);
                            output += c;
                          }

                      }
                       System.out.println();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction("com.curie.WEIGHT_RECEIVED");
                        intent.putExtra("Output",output);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcastSync(intent);

                        // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //an exception here marks connection loss
                    //send message to UI Activity
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am receiving the data correctly when I check the string that gets received by the BroadcastReceiver so that is not the issue.

Also I do not need to update the screen every time, i could update it every second or so if that would make it better? Thank you.

EDIT: Added handler is not compiling. please help.
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            //Log.d("workkkkkk","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$****** printingggggg ******$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
            while (true) {
                //counter++;

                try {
                    output = "";
                    //read the data from socket stream
                    //mmInStream != null && counter%10000000 == 1
                    if(mmInStream != null) {
                        mmInStream.read(buffer);
                        for(byte b : buffer)
                        {
                            char c = (char) b;
                            if(c >=' ' && c <'z') {
                                // System.out.print(c);
                                output += c;
                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction("com.curie.WEIGHT_RECEIVED");
                        intent.putExtra("Output",output);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(inputContext).sendBroadcastSync(intent);

                        // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(InputActivity.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //an exception here marks connection loss
                    //send message to UI Activity
                    break;
                }
            }
 inputContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // here do the UI chnages
                                //  you can set text in textview Here

                            }
                        });

        }


    });
```

Comment: what `setInputWindow()` method do?

Comment: It just calls ` inputWindow.setText(weight);` i was using it to try to put delays in to see if that would help.

Comment: so `inputWindow.setText(weight);` after `inputWindow.setText("helloooooooo worldddddd"` will change it to `weight` can you tell what is the value of wight?

Comment: I can tell what the value of weight is when I print it to the console, but it does not appear when I call `setText()` but even `inputWindow.setText("helloooooooo worldddddd")` wont work unless I comment out `connector.run()`

Comment: you need to run your `run` method in worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For background work use handler(use this code)

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // here do the background task

            }
        });
```

and if u want to update UI use runOnUiThread()

```
              if u want  to update ui Just do this
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // here do the UI chnages
                    }
                });
```

Hope this will help you.

Do like this

```
  @Override
public void run() {
    // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
    //Log.d("workkkkkk","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$****** printingggggg ******$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    while (true) {
        //counter++;

        try {
            output = "";
            //read the data from socket stream
            //mmInStream != null && counter%10000000 == 1
            if(mmInStream != null) {
                mmInStream.read(buffer);
                for(byte b : buffer)
                {
                    char c = (char) b;
                    if(c >=' ' && c <'z') {
                        // System.out.print(c);
                        output += c;
                    }

                }
               // context == activity context
               context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // here do the UI chnages
                      //  you can set text in textview Here
                    }
                });


            }
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //an exception here marks connection loss
            //send message to UI Activity
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

});

Comment: would both of these methods go in my non UI class? how do I specity what activity to act on?

Comment: Just pass the context of Activity in to your non ui class through constructor then,
With the help of Context you can get these methods and do your work.

Comment: Is it not better to use an [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) has it automatically manages both the background thread and the communication with the main (UI) thread?

Comment: Yes, You can use Async Task depend on the requirement.

Comment: where do I put the runOnUiThread? i am struggling with implementing this.

Comment: I have posted what my handler looks like, it still wont compile, what am I doing wrong?